# Jquery validation pulgin submitting invalid form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-ui

i am using the jquery validation plugin to validate my form..i am having a problem, where my form is getting submitted even tough there are invalid fields upon clicking submit button..Not sure where i am doing wrong..help needed..

jsp file:

```
    <%@include file="././Header.jsp"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<c:set var="baseUrl" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
<script src="<c:url value="/js/smlibray/emailCommunicate.js"/>"></script>
 <link href="<c:url value="/js/jquery-ui.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="<c:url value="/js/jquery-ui.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/siteMinderAppWeb/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"/></script>

<input type="hidden" name="applicationUrl" id="applicationUrl"
    value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">

<div class="container sec-container middle-sec">
    <div class="form-fields row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <form:form class="form-horizontal policy-form" id="emailCommu-form" name="emailCommu-form" method="POST" modelAttribute="emailForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                <h1 class="email-header">SiteMidner Email Notification</h1>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${not empty sMsg}">
                        <div class="email-Commu-SMsg">* ${sMsg}</div>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <c:if test="${not empty eMsg}">
                            <div class="email-Commu-EMsg">* ${eMsg}</div>
                        </c:if>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                <div class="form-emailCommu">
                    <label for="emailSub-txtArea" class="email-ContentHead">Enter
                        the Subject Line for the Email : </label>
                    <div class="email-sm-textDiv">
                        <form:textarea path="emailSubject" name="emailSubTxtArea" id="emailSubTxtArea"
                            placeholder="Email Subject"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-emailCommu">
                    <label for="emailBod-txtArea" class="email-ContentHead">Enter
                        the Message Body for the Email : </label>
                    <div class="email-sm-textDiv">
                        <form:textarea path="emailMsg" name="emailBodyTxtArea" id="emailBodyTxtArea"
                            placeholder="Email Body"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="email-sendButton">
                    <input type="submit" class="styled-button" value="Send Email"></input>
                </div>
                </div>
            </form:form>

        </div>
        <!--form-fields close -->
    </div>
</div>
```

js file which has validate method:-

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        highlight: function(element) {
          $(element)
            .closest('.form-group')
            .addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
          $(element)
            .closest('.form-group')
            .removeClass('has-error');
        },
            errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
    });
    $("#emailCommu-form").submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
       }).validate({
        rules:{
            emailSubTxtArea:{
                required:true
            },
            emailBodyTxtArea: {
                required:true
            }

        },
        messages:{
            emailSubTxtArea:{
                required: 'Email Subject cannot be empty.'
            },
            emailBodyTxtArea: {
                required: 'Email body msg cannot be empty.',
            }
        },  
        submitHandler:function(form){
            //var jsonObj = getData();      
            if(confirm("You are about to send Email Communication, Click Ok if you want to proceed..?")){
            form.submit();
        }
        }
    });
```

thanks...

Comment: 2 important things to check...does form exist when you run this code and are there any errors in browser console that would block this code

Comment: Don't see where you even include your own code in the page or that jQuery.js is included

Comment: hI Charlietfl, i dont see any errors in te console and form is appearing fine and does submitting with invalid fields upon submit..does you see any errors in my code..?

Comment: appearing fine and exists when code runs aren't the same thing though. Is your code inside a `document.ready` handler? I assume it is included in page but not shown in page outline?

Comment: obviously yes Charlietfl..previously i used ajax for the submission and then it worked fine..But now i made the changes and done it through form handler submission..does using <form:form> makes a difference..?

Comment: So you get the  confirm dialog and it submits if form is empty...is that the invalid submission?

Comment: yea..the case is,upon clicking the submit, it needs to first validate if fields are empty or not..and if they arent then needs to get confirm dialog..

Comment: Right...that would be expected...but you get the dialog even when it's empty? (Or one is empty)

Comment: yea..i am getting the dialog, even when they are empty..

Comment: Can you copy source html and reproduce in jsfiddle.net or other js sandbox. Can get validate plugin from numerous different CDN's

Comment: Charlietfi, what i found was, when i dont inlcude form tags like <form:from> and <from:inputarea> the validation is working fine..

Comment: jsp not my area of expertise. Does it generate proper html in browser? Double check typos too ... you just made 2...`from` should be `form`

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the issue,by making the same name for the path-name and html-name attribute..With spring form tag,path is mandatory while id and name are not mandatory...it seems spring form tag will autogenerate the id and name with the same name as path field..so replacing my html-name with same as path-name fixed the issue..

```
<form:textarea path="emailSubject" name="emailSubject" id="emailSubTxtArea"
                            placeholder="Email Subject"/>
```